# Problems met with malloc(strlen(char*)+1)

Tags: c

In below is a small test for my confusion during programing with C.

```
int main()
{
    char buff[100] = {};
    char* pStr = NULL;

    printf("Input the string\n");
    if (!fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin))
    {
        printf("ERROR INPUT\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%zd\n", strlen(buff));
    pStr = (char*)malloc(strlen(buff)+1);
    strcpy_s(pStr, sizeof(buff), buff);
    printf("%s\n", strlen(pStr));

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use `fgets` to capture the input string and store it in the memory assigned by `malloc`.  However, when I try to use `malloc(strlen(char*)+1)`, the program compiled without bug but ran failed. Once I switch to `malloc(sizeof(buff))`, it works fine. I am quite confused. Thus searching for helps from you.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  For both languages you have issues.

Comment: This looks like [tag:c] if so remove the [tag:c++]

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but take a look at that call to `malloc`, how many bytes do you allocate? Then take a look at the next line with your `strcpy_s` call, how many bytes *can* you copy there? The length in the `strcpy_s` call is the size of the *destination* buffer.

Comment: PS: You do not need the cast on `malloc`

Comment: You mean `char buff[100] = {'\0'}`, right? Otherwise this code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: "when I try to use malloc(strlen(char*)+1), the program compiled without bug" - no it didn't.  It *can't* have.  Maybe you meant `sizeof( char * ) + 1`, but calling `strlen` with an argument of `char *` *will* make the compiler yak.

Comment: Surely you meant `printf("%s\n", pStr);`.  I'd recommend `printf("<%s>\n", pStr);` to clearly see leading/trailing white space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strcpy_s(pStr, sizeof(buff), buff);` isn't correct, you should use the size of the new target buffer, not the size of the source buffer

Just replace the whole thing with

```
size_t size = strlen(buff)+1;
pStr = malloc(size);
memcpy(pStr, buff, size);
```

As a little bonus, this code is also faster.

Comment: Lundin, Thanks for your help. Is it safe to say when copying strings from buffer to a memroy region, the memcpy is better than strcpy_s?

Comment: @xiaoshi When you know the length of the string, use memcpy since it is fastest. When you don't know the length of the string, you can use strcpy_s.